# wpf mvvm populate model data object in viewmodel from different window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am creating a simple MVVM application and heres what it does,

1) Show details in a data grid from after reading json file.

2) Add new record into the collection and save the json file .

My problem is when Add button is pressed in the MainWindow I am opening a AddContacts window that has an Add button. Now when the Add button is pressed in the AddContacts window how do I get the Contacts object data so I can add to the ContactsList in the ContactListViewModel. Both AddContact Window and MainWindow data context is  ContactListViewModel. 
Typically I will have another Command for the add button in AddWindow in ContactListViewModel. But please help me populate the model data.

So I created a Model as follows;

```
public class Contacts:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    private string _dateOfBirth;
    public string DateOfBirth
    {
        get { return _dateOfBirth; }
        set
        {
            _dateOfBirth = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DateOfBirth");
        }
    }
    private string _weight;
    public string Weight
    {
        get { return _weight; }
        set
        {
            _weight = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Weight");
        }
    }
    private string _height;
    public string Height
    {
        get { return _height; }
        set
        {
            _height = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Height");
        }
    }
    private string _phone;
    public string Phone
    {
        get { return _phone; }
        set
        {
            _phone = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Phone");
        }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have the view model as follows;

```
    public class ContactListViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Contacts> _contactsCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<Contacts> ContactsCollection
        {
            get { return _contactsCollection; }
            set { _contactsCollection = value; }
        }

        private RelayCommand _addCommand;
        public ICommand AddCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_addCommand == null)
                {
                    _addCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.OpenAddWindow());
                }
                return _addCommand;
            }
        }

        private void OpenAddWindow()
        {
            AddContact contact = new AddContact();
            contact.DataContext = this;
            contact.ShowDialog();
        }

        public ContactListViewModel()
        {

            //As discussed below using a thread.
            Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CreateSampleContacts));
            th.Start();

        }



        //Im hardcoding some contacts but I want to remove the hardcoding and 
 //add data thats coming from AddWindow
        public void CreateSampleContacts()
        {
            List<Contacts> contactsList = new List<Contacts>();
            contactsList.Add(new Contacts
            {
                FirstName = "Nikhil",
                LastName = "ANS",
                DateOfBirth = "07/12/1989",
                Weight = "184 lbs",
                Height = "6.0 feet",
                Phone = "805-251-1015"
            });

            contactsList.Add(new Contacts
            {
                FirstName = "Sam",
                LastName = "B",
                DateOfBirth = "04/10/1991",
                Weight = "174 lbs",
                Height = "5.10 feet",
                Phone = "800-800-8000"
            });

            contactsList.Add(new Contacts
            {
                FirstName = "Henry",
                LastName = "K",
                DateOfBirth = "05/06/1988",
                Weight = "184 lbs",
                Height = "6.4 feet",
                Phone = "408-408-4088"
            });

            if (contactsList.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    CreateJsonandWrite(contactsList);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
             }
        }

        public async void CreateJsonandWrite(List<Contacts> allContacts)
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allContacts);
            await WriteToFile(json);
        }

        public Task WriteToFile(string json)
        {
            string path = "~/Contacts.json";
            return WriteTextToFileAsync(path, json);
        }

       //Asynchronosly writing data to the file
        public async Task WriteTextToFileAsync(string filePath, string text)
        {
            byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

            using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
                FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
                bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
            {
                await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
            };
        }
    }
```

Main Window

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Height="25" Width="80">Add</Button>
            <Button Height="25" Width="80">Delete</Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsCollection}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding DateOfBirth}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Weight}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Height}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Phone}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

AddWindow

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock>First Name : </TextBlock>
            <TextBox Margin="20,0,0,0" Height="25" Width="120" Text="{Binding FirstName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock>Last Name :</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Margin="20,0,0,0" Height="25" Width="120" Text="{Binding LastName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBlock>Date of Birth :</TextBlock>
            <DatePickerTextBox Height="25" Width="120" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding DateOfBirth,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,StringFormat='dd/mm/yyyy'}">

            </DatePickerTextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3">
            <TextBlock>Width :</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Margin="45,0,0,0" Height="25" Width="120" Text="{Binding Weight,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="4">
            <TextBlock>Height :</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Margin="42,0,0,0" Height="25" Width="120" Text="{Binding Height,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="5">
            <TextBlock>Phone :</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Margin="44,0,0,0" Height="25" Width="120" Text="{Binding Phone,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <Button Grid.Row="6" Margin="45">Add</Button>
```

//When this add button is pressed I want to get the data in //ContactListViewModel for the Contacts object.

Comment: Try switching these two lines. `contact.ShowDialog();
            contact.DataContext = this;`. The way you have it prevents the DataContext to be set until you close the dialog window.

Comment: thanks I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from childwindow to parentwindow you need to follow the steps

1. In Add button click event of childwindow add **DialogResult = true**
2. In ParentWindow modify your openAddWindow method as

   ```
   private void OpenAddWindow()
   {
       AddContact contact = new AddContact();
       contact.DataContext = this;
       if(contact.ShowDialog() == true)
       {
            //here i have just given messagebox here you can fetch the data membersof AddContact window
            MessageBox.Show(contact.VariableAssumed);
            //On add button click in childwindow You can save your new contact in Contacts object(newContact) 
            //and you can retrieve the newContact here and add it to your Contact list present in parentwindow as below
            contactList.Add(contact.newContact);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi Satish,

Thanks for the answer. I am having confusion with this step //On add button click in childwindow You can save your new contact in Contacts object(newContact) .

Could you please post some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Just am trying make out an example of  the classes what you have posted. Hope this helps

AddContact class

```
class AddContact
{
   ....
   public Contacts newContact{get;set;}
   public AddContact()
   {
       newContact = new Contacts();
   }

   private void  OnAddButtonClicked()
   {
      newContact.FirstName = "Abc";//just i am taking abc asexample you fetch data from the textbox controls
      newContact.LastName = "Abc";
      .....
      //fill all the data members
      DialogResult = true;
      this.close();
   }
}
```

ContactListViewModel class

```
class ContactListViewModel 
{
     .....
     private ObservableCollection<Contacts> _contactsCollection;
     private void OpenAddWindow()
     {
         AddContact contact = new AddContact();
         contact.DataContext = this;
         if(contact.ShowDialog() == true)
         {
              _contactsCollection.Add(contact.newContact);
         }
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm very surprised that the right answer didn't appear here.

I will try to explain you how to proceed.

First of all, you need to use something which is able to contain all your referenced ViewModel during the runtime of your app.

Download and install the MVVM Toolkit package nuget.

After that, try to use a ViewModelLocator :

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ContactListViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }

    public static ContactListViewModel ContactListVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ContactListViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public static void CleanContactList()
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<ContactListViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ContactListViewModel>();
    }

    public static MainViewModel MainVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public static void CleanMain()
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }

    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        CleanMain();
        CleanContactList();
    }
}
```

Here is [a link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/viewmodel-locator-in-wpf/) to allow you how to instanciate your ViewModelLocator correctly.

After that, anywhere you are in your code, you can call any ViewModel by its static attribute in the **ViewModelLocator** and set any properties into it.